# How to position the nvd3(angularjs) legend position to the left of pie chart?

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/pieChart. I want the legend of pie chart to be in the left of the pie chart. There is an option legendPosition,it works for the right position but not for the left position. Should I use css to do this or any way around?

Answer (score 0):

Using css is the easy way around.